Create a cron job to update Woocommerce products stock status based on custom fields
I'm trying to create a cron job that will compare a date set as product metadata to the current date, then update the product stock if the date set as product metadata has passed.
Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't work:
// Custom CRON Function
function update_pre_order_stock_status($post_id){

        $current_date = date( 'YYYY-mm-dd' );
        $expiryDate = $product->get_meta('woo_expiry_date');
        $woo_expiry_action = $product->get_meta('woo_expiry_action');
        $product_category = array( 'comic-book-pre-orders', 'dc-comics-pre-orders', 'image-comics-pre-orders', 'manga-pre-orders', 'marvel-comics-pre-orders', 'other-publisher-pre-orders');
    
        if(( is_product_category( $product_category )) && ( $expiryDate <= $current_date ) && ( $woo_expiry_action == 'out' )) {
            
            // 1. Updating the stock quantity
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', 0);

            // 2. Updating the stock quantity
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', wc_clean( 'outofstock' ) );

            // 3. Updating post term relationship
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'outofstock', 'product_visibility', true );
        }
}

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_pre_order_stock_update' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_pre_order_stock_update' );
}

add_action( 'my_pre_order_stock_update', 'update_pre_order_stock_status' );

The Cron event 'my_pre_order_stock_update' shows up in the cron list, but running it isn't doing anything.
Any recommendations would be very much appreciated!

Where is located this code? Where are you using it (on admin edit product page or on single product pages)? A bit more context will be useful.

Hi LoicTheAztec,
Code is located in my functions file, and the intention is to update the stock status in the admin edit product page... which would also update the stock on single product page I assume.
The meta 'woo_expiry_date' and 'woo_expiry_action' are added to the products when I bulk upload them via a csv file.
'woo_expiry_date' column entries have a date with the format of 'YYYY-mm-dd'.
'woo_expiry_action' column entires have the option 'out'.
Let me know if you need any additional information, thank you for your help!

There are many mistakes in your code:

The variable $post_id is not defined as you are not passing any post ID argument to wp_next_scheduled and wp_schedule_event functions.
The variable $product is not defined either (and can't be defined actually).

I assume that you are trying to update some specific products based on:

their assigned product category based on a list of term slugs
a date custom metadata in woo_expiry_date
a value custom metadata in woo_expiry_action

So you need to get those products IDs via a WP_Query which will be the simplest way.
Now as WooCommerce is migrating to custom tables since version 3, and as some product data is cached, you should not use WordPress post meta functions anymore.
Try the following instead (untested):
// Custom Cron hooked Function called by wp_schedule_event
add_action( 'jape_pre_order_stock_update', 'update_pre_order_stock_status' );
function update_pre_order_stock_status(){
    // Get all related product IDs to update via a WP_Query
    $products_ids = get_posts( [
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1, // <= the number of products to process (-1 is all)
        'fields'      => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array(
                'comic-book-pre-orders',
                'dc-comics-pre-orders',
                'image-comics-pre-orders',
                'manga-pre-orders',
                'marvel-comics-pre-orders',
                'other-publisher-pre-orders',
            ),
        ) ),
        'meta_query' => array( 
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'value'   => 'instock',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'woo_expiry_date',
                'value'   => date_i18n('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'woo_expiry_action',
                'value'   => 'out',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    ] );

    foreach( $products_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        $product->set_stock_quantity(0); // Set stock quantity
        $product->set_stock_status('outofstock'); // Set stock status
        $product->save(); // Save updated product data
    }
}

// Cron schedule event function
function cron_starter_hourly_products_update() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'jape_pre_order_stock_update' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'jape_pre_order_stock_update' );
    }
}

cron_starter_hourly_products_update(); // Initiate cron schedule event

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work.
Caution: The number of product to process should be fine-tuned in 'numberposts' argument, as if there are too many products to process, it may crash the scheduled event or even the website.
Related:

Use WooCommerce WC_Order object with wp_schedule_event
Save a database query and update it automatically every X hours. Wordpress
Reset coupon usage limit after a specified time in WooCommerce


Hi LoicTheAztec,
Sorry the timing of the cron wasn't working so I've done some more testing.
Seems the date format needs to be the Wordpress format... I'm guessing it takes the format in the metadata and converts it to match the Wordpress format perhaps?
Anyway it seems to be working with the code updated to ''value' => date('Y-m-d')'.
Manually running the cron with this change works as expected, I'm waiting for midnight (2 hours) for the cron to automatically run as a final test.

I thought it would be rude to update your answer / code, so was planning on adding the updated code once the final test was done, with the 'array(
'key'  => '_stock_status',
'value'  => 'instock',
'compare' => '=',' and ''value'  => date('Y-m-d'),' code added.

I have updated my answer meta query with your last provided data arrays from your comment. Note that my initial answer was showing you the right way to do things, as I couldn't really test it in real world on my side…

Hi LoicTheAztec, so I was still having trouble with the time comparison.
Not sure if it was a timezone issue or that the comparison needed a 'type' for Wordpress to know what was going on, but after a little research and whole lot of trial and error... I think it's now working using this array for date comparison: 'array(
'key'  => 'woo_expiry_date',
'value'  => date_i18n('Y-m-d'),
'compare' => '<=',
'type'   => 'DATE',
),'
I'll check it over the next couple of days, but I think we're good. Thanks again for all your help!
